# Enabling multiple operations in a calculator via vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to practice my js and I'm doing a calculator project. I've got it to work but I can only do one calculation. I'm stuck and I need to be able to carry out multiple operations. Please note I'm not yet done with the project and so i'm testing for functionality, also some buttons are yet to be worked on. I've also been advised not to use eval() method.

Here is what I need help with:

** Users should be able to string together several operations and get the right answer, with each pair of numbers being evaluated at a time. For example, 12 + 7 - 5 * 3 = should yield 42.**

```
let add = function(a,b) {
  return a + b;
}
let subtract = function(a,b) {
  return a - b;
}
let multiply = function(a,b) {
  return a * b;
}
let divide = function(a,b) {
  return a / b;
}
let operator = function(operate,a,b) {
  if (operate === '+') {
    return add(a,b);
  } else if (operate === '-') {
    return subtract(a,b);
  } else if (operate === '*') {
    return multiply(a,b);
  } else if (operate === '/') {
    return divide(a,b);
  }
}
let screen = document.querySelector('div');
let buttons = document.querySelector('.btns');
let data = ''
let numOne = ''
let numTwo = ''
let result = ''
let operatorSymbol = ''
buttons.addEventListener('click', e => {
  data += e.target.value;
  screen.textContent = data;
  if ((e.target.value === '+') || (e.target.value === '-') || (e.target.value === '*') || 
  (e.target.value === '/')){
    numOne = data.slice(0,-1);
    operatorSymbol += e.target.value;
  }
  numTwo = data.slice(-((data.length-1) - numOne.length));
  if(e.target.value === '='){
    data=data.slice(0,-1);
    numTwo=numTwo.slice(0,-1);
    result=operator(operatorSymbol,+numOne,+numTwo);
    data = result;
    screen.textContent = data;
}
})
```

The full webpage can be found here :  https://repl.it/@socman/SweetZealousLearning#app.js

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you end up with a string like "12+7-5*3". One option is to use regex to parse the string and do the math on the resulting array. This is not the only way, but for simple equations like the ones you have, it should work.

```js
// Perform math operation on 2 values
function doMath(op1, op, op2)
{
  if (op === '+') return op1 + op2;
  if (op === '-') return op1 - op2;
  if (op === '*') return op1 * op2;
  if (op === '/') return op1 / op2;
  return 0; // error
}

// Test string
const eq = "12+7-5*3";

// Parse with regex
const regex = /\d+|[-+\*\/]/g;
const parsed = eq.match(regex);

// Store first number (12 in the example)
if (parsed && parsed.length && !isNaN(parsed[0])) {
  let result = Number(parsed[0]);
  for (let i = 1; i < eq.length - 1; i++) {
    // Do the math with previous result and next number
    if ("+-*/".includes(parsed[i]) && !isNaN(parsed[i+1])) {
      result = doMath(result, parsed[i], Number(parsed[i+1]));
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```